# Bootstrap grid system lining up two labels next to each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to line these two labels and inputs together. Will someone please tell me where I may be going wrong? I just want them to be lined up next to each other.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label for="gender_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Sex:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <cfinclude template="../ddl/gender.cfm">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label for="driverlicense_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label><cfinclude template="../includes/tooltip.cfm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <cfoutput>
                    <cfinclude template="../ddl/dlstates.cfm">  <!--- If you need to re-insert into HTML and not use as include, then you have to correct the file location i.e(../../../) --->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="driverlicense_#Add#" id="driverlicense_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#session.checkout.info["driverlicense_" & Add]#" />
                    </cfoutput>
                    <span id="result_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How do I put the Driver License Number on the same line as sex?

**EDIT**

Changing it to col-lg-6 puts them on the same line but they still end up looking like this? I am trying to have them not look so awful.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <label for="gender_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Sex:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <cfinclude template="../ddl/gender.cfm">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <label for="driverlicense_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label><cfinclude template="../includes/tooltip.cfm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <cfoutput>
                    <cfinclude template="../ddl/dlstates.cfm">  <!--- If you need to re-insert into HTML and not use as include, then you have to correct the file location i.e(../../../) --->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="driverlicense_#Add#" id="driverlicense_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#session.checkout.info["driverlicense_" & Add]#" />
                    </cfoutput>
                    <span id="result_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How do I remove Driver license number more to the left to make it look better?

Comment: Instead of `col-lg-12` try `col-lg-6`

Comment: Follow the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: @j08691 that does put them on the same line but the gaps are huge and I wanted the select of sex to be the same size as the one above it

Comment: You should read up on how Bootstrap's grid system works.

Comment: @j08691 
 
can you check edit 2 to see where I am stuck? I cant move drivers license number more to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use col-lg-6 classes instead of col-lg-12 to enable these two elements to take 6-6 column. So they can fit into the very same row.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="gender_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Sex:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <cfinclude template="../ddl/gender.cfm">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <label for="driverlicense_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label><cfinclude template="../includes/tooltip.cfm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <cfoutput>
                <cfinclude template="../ddl/dlstates.cfm">  <!--- If you need to re-insert into HTML and not use as include, then you have to correct the file location i.e(../../../) --->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="driverlicense_#Add#" id="driverlicense_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#session.checkout.info["driverlicense_" & Add]#" />
                </cfoutput>
                <span id="result_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand that but how do i close in on such a large gap and control the size of the select to match the one above it? The selects are shrinking when I use less than 12

Comment: It happens because with col-lg-6 you occupy the half of the virtual columns in the layout. However, you use only 1+3 columns from his 6 available ones for your elements.

If you would like to match the existing layout, you can either use col-lg-4 and col-lg-8 instead of the current col-lg-6 classes and in the form-group add col-lg-4, col-lg-4 to the two elements.

Or you can put gender dropdown, license dropdown and the text into separate col-lg-4 rows. So they will be in equal distance.

Comment: can you show me an example of how the code should look

Comment: Updated the answer. You can fiddle with the numbers within the form-group if you don't want the dropdown and the textfield equal width.

Comment: can you check edit 2 to see where I am stuck? I cant move drivers license number more to the left

Comment: I think you should use col-lg-4 instead of col-lg-5. I think the previous lines are all split in 4-4-4 ratio. If you use 5 for gender, driver license number will start in the 6th column instead of the 5th.

That blank area is occupied by the empty space AFTER gender. Not the empty space before license number.

Answer (score 1):

They are both 12 columns wide. Try make them 6, hence half the size.

Comment: I understand that but how do i close in on such a large gap and control the size of the select to match the one above it? The selects are shrinking when I use less than 12

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain better?

Comment: the sex select should be the same size as the one in the picture above it for month of date of birth. Then drivers license number should start where select day distance is

Comment: Maybe give more space to the select and less to the label sex? Like 4 to the label and 8 to the select

Comment: can you check edit 2 to see where I am stuck? I cant move drivers license number more to the left

Comment: In the edit 3 you are being inconsistent with sizes. In the secon internal block the sum of the column sizes is 7. In the first internal block 10.